# Taking pictures off a line in HTML5

Tags: html, web

I'm working on an very, very, very basic website, so basic it's pure HTML. I could easily add CSS, but for simplicities sake I'm trying to just do it in HTML. I have a banner I want to put at the top of the page, then I want it to drop a line and have the rest of the pictures there. I can get the pictures to easily popup in rows and have them resized, but some pictures still go onto the line which the banner is on. I don't want that. Would I need to somehow use a break? Again, trying to stay away from using CSS because I feel as though putting 5 lines of it on a website is a bit silly. However it's what you strongly suggest, I'm fine with doing it.

Comment: What? I don't understand what your are trying to do. Can you show your code. And also, why do you not want to use CSS?

Comment: I did sound strongly against CSS, my bad. I'm just curious if there's a way to do it within HTML. I have 3 rows of pictures, and a banner at the top. The pictures are going onto the toprow, along with the banner, which I don't want them to do.

Comment: http://nashread.com.previewdns.com
I don't know if you can connect to this, but here. @putvande

Comment: If you want a line break after the banner, just use a line break `<br>`, or wrap them in `<div>`.

Comment: The pictures are still going onto the top line.

Comment: I've tried div, p, br and anything else I can think of.

Comment: Oh good lord, I'm a dumbass. I forgot a ", which made all of the pictures under one link and all of the code not work. Thank you everyone, anyways -_-